# Recommendations for 3.5 switching audio jack which does NOT short to Ground at plug-in or plug-out?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, connector

I have been using a 3.5 mm switching Audio Jack in order to charge/switch-on and off my RC-Glider model. For this I connected the battery of my RC-glider to the one-part of the audio jack and the electronics to the other side. The audio jack I use seems to be a [SJ1-3515](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/interconnect/connectors/audio-connectors/jacks/sj1-351x-series) (although, I am not sure as this switch was delivered with the model). Here are the schematics: [image: Schematics of my wiring]

However I noticed that whenever I plug-in or plug-out a cable, ground is shortly connected to either of the two other pins, which then of course **shorts-out** my battery! This led to high-current and some very hot wires which desoldered my connections to the switch. Obviously I do not want to short my battery every time I plug-in or plug-out the charger or the on-off insert.

Therefore my question(s):

1. Is this a normal behavior for a switching 3.5mm Jack?
2. Can someone tell me if non-shorting-out 3.5mm Jack connectors exist, and how to find those? Or am I just plainly using the wrong tool for the job?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Per demand I included a (badly drawn) schematic.
Edit2: Generalized the question such that I ask for the **class** of non-shorting products instead of a specific product.

Comment: Show the schematic of how both sides of the jack is wired with respect to any other connection, particularly the battery.

Comment: Shorting is normal for audio jacks. Maybe it's preferred behavior. You can put a polymer fuse in series with the battery but if someone leaves the plug half in it will drain the battery fairly quickly.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes that is normal, the sleeve connection of the jack most likely touches the tip and ring when plugging and unplugging.
2. Yes, wiring large battery currents via a short-prone audio connector rated for 1A max current does seem like a bad idea. It is a completely wrong tool for the job. There are far more suitable connectors available that are designed for connecting DC power (instead of audio), such as the common barrel plugs.

Comment: 1. Yes I see that. This is exactly what happens
2. Please explain why. The battery is by no means large. As explained in the post, the maximum current I expect is 0.5A, that is a 50% margin. 

I see why 1. is a deal-braker, but that is why I ask: Is there a way to rectify this problem?

Comment: Just a clarification:

1. Yes I see that (the switch has a transparent cover).

Comment: 0.5A when it is running? Short circuit current can be many times that.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But as mentioned before: I **don't** want to short my battery, as that would definitly violate the specs of the battery. So instead of searching for a switch that can support the current spike of the short circuit, I am searching for a switch (or a suitable alternative) which does **not* short the battery.

Comment: I understand. But seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic here. Have you tried searching at all? There are many distributors that sell connectors suitable for high currents and do not short out.

Comment: I have searched. That is where I found the product which I linked in the original question. But you just mentioned "[...] sell connectors [which] do not short out". That is exactly my question. I apologize if I violated the rules here, but perhaps instead of recommending a specific product, could you tell me what I am searching for? How are products labeled which do not short out? Because for example the Datasheet which I linked, does not mention any "shorting out".

Comment: Then you have to switch away from 3.5mm audio jacks and switch to connectors that are actually meant for connecting DC power supplies, like DC barrell plugs and jacks.

Comment: That is a good tip! I could only find barrel plugs which connect only one circuit at a time, while I would like to have two. But perhaps I will find something suitable. Why dont you edit your answer in order to reflect this proposition? Then I will accept it.